# Flutter Unit Test Error :: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'RxString'

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I am building an App on Flutter and have used GetX as Dependency Manager. I am writing unit test to test the functionality of function inside a Controller. However, when I run the tests, the get the error as follows.

Here is my controller class :

```dart
class SwitchController extends GetxController {
  final visitsController = Get.put(DateNavigationController());
  var selectedPill = "week".obs;
  var labelIndex = 0.obs;
}
```

Since I'm using GetX as state management solution too, .obs at the end of the variable makes it reactive.

All I'm trying to do is check the value of `selectedPill` if it is initialized to "week" or not.

I'm using Mockito for Mocking my Controller class and the code goes as below:

```dart
class MockSwitchController extends Mock implements SwitchController {}

void main() {
  late MockSwitchController sut;

  setUp(() {
    sut = MockSwitchController();
  });

  tearDown(() {
    sut.dispose();
  });

   test('check the value of selectedPill', () {
      expect(sut.selectedPill.value, "week");
    });
```

However, when running the test, I'm getting an error which says " type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'RxString'".

I am not able to wrap my head around where the problem is actually arising here and what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead pressing run button under test, press debug under the main function to see more detail.
When you use Mock, you should tell when a function called, what should be returned.

Comment: Can you explain more with some example?